# Vector.push_back(std::function<void()>); way around compiler asking for expression

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

If I wrirte:

Vector.push_back(std::function<void()>);

Compiler tries to interpret it as the expression and fails..
My way around was:

```
std::function<void()> fun;
Vector.push_back(fun);
```

Is there a way to fix this in one line?

Comment: You need to initialize an object: `Vector.push_back(std::function<void()>{});`

Comment: `std::function<void()>` is a *type*, you can't store types. If you need an instance of that type, then create such an instance (as shown by @Yksisarvinen).

Comment: If you try to increase the size of the vector, have a look at the functions `reserve` and `resize` of `std::vector`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the same reason why this:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(int);
```

won't work. You need an object, not a type:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(int{}); // notice the {}
```

Similarily, your:

```
Vector.push_back(std::function<void()>);
```

Tries to push a type, not an object. Create one the same way:

```
Vector.push_back(std::function<void()>{}); // notice the {}
```